# Finding unbiased point estimate of population variance

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Q.The contents of each of a random sample of 100 cans of a soft drink are measured. The results have a mean of 331.28 ml and a standard deviation of 2.97 ml. Show that an unbiased estimate of the population variance is 8.91 ml.

I'm only able to get 2.97^2 which is 8.8209 but that is not what the question wants. How do I obtain 8.91? From my knowledge, an unbiased estimate of population variance is the same as sample variance, so 8.8209 should have been the correct answer, but it isn't. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

The unbiased estimator for the variance of the population is

$$s_u^2=\frac1{n-1}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n ( x_i-\overline x)^2$$

While the variance of the sample is

$$s^2=\frac1n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n ( x_i-\overline x)^2=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot s_u^2$$

I think you can go on.

**Remark:**

I´ve found out, that you can paste **2.97^2*100/99** into the google search box without making any formatting. After pressing enter immediately the result is shown. See [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox&q=2.97%5E2*100%2F99).

Answer (score 2):

The [unbiased sample variance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1hgiAla3KI) is $\hat{\sigma}^2 \times \frac{n}{n-1}$. So, it should be 2.97^2*100/99.